# Show error and change doneLabel of rich:fileUpload in upload listener method

Tags: jsf, file-upload, richfaces, message

I have to upload CSV file and I have to validate some values of file, for example does not allow negative value. Then, I need validate it and that file does not apear like "done" or "uploaded". I need handle an error on display it.

```
<rich:fileUpload
    fileUploadListener="#{configClientBean.listener}"

    ontyperejected="alert('some error');"
    maxFilesQuantity="1"
    onuploadcomplete="#{rich:component('waitPanelInterno')}.hide();"
    onfilesubmit="#{rich:component('waitPanelInterno')}.show();"
    render="pnlMensajes, idTableClients, scrollRegistros, outputPanelDetalle"
    autoclear="true">

    <rich:message for="uploadConfigClient" />

    <a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" execute="popupFileLoad"
    render="panelCarga, pnlMensajes" />

</rich:fileUpload>
```

In the Backing bean I can validate some things, but I cant show errors or change the behavior of "rich:fileUpload" compoment for example doneLable can not be displayed.

```
public void listener(FileUploadEvent event) throws Exception {

    try {
        UploadedFile file = event.getUploadedFile();
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getData());
        InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(bais, getMessage("iso"));
        BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(is);
        while ((registro = bufRead.readLine()) != null) {
            if(cvsLine[1].isEmpty()){
            // stop process
            // Throw error
            }
        }
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please elaborate "I cant show errors". How exactly can't you show errors? What exactly happens instead?

Answer (score 0):

To add extra behavior to the `rich:fileUpload` component that is not default is by creating your own file upload component (ex. `myown:fileUpload`) based on the `rich:fileUpload` [source code](https://github.com/richfaces4) and the use of the [Component Development Kit](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesCDKHowTos).

A second solution could be by adding one extra message field that is described in this post: [RichFaces fileupload and h:message problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348055/richfaces-fileupload-and-hmessage-problem)